# sending email from vmware sandbox using tomcat

Tags: linux, email, tomcat, virtual-machine

I have a simple tomcat servlet application, no Java EE.  Also, I am running a development sandbox behind vmware NAT and behind a linksys 192.168 network.  Of course, I can access the internet from my sandbox in an outgoing way, but I would like to know if I can setup javamail on this sandbox, without JBoss, and what do I need to do in the RHEL 6 configuration to make it possible to send outgoing mail.

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javamail is a Java library, like any other.

Regardless what you're doing - sending outgoing SMTP message, getting POP3 mail or anything else, simply package it together with your webapp and use it.

You will of course need a SMTP relay server, but this is completely off-topic.